# Evaluate double integral $ \int _0^{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_y^{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin (y^2 )\; dydx$

Tags: integration

$$
\int _0^{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_y^{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin (y^2
)\; dydx$$
Even if I change the order of integration I don't see how to get rid of this $\sin (x^2)$ which doesn't have antiderivate. It is possible to evaluate it without using any aproximation method?

Comment: Is the integrand $\sin^2{x}$?

Comment: In the notation $dy\, dx$ we integrate w.r.t. y first, right? Some books say the opposite. So just clarifying. Here it seems you'd integrate w.r.t. x first.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a correction.

Comment: @michaelaba: what do you have to say about what I asked above? Am i right?

Comment: Yes, it is y first

Comment: @michaelaba It can't be so IMO. If you integrate w.r.t $y$ first and put $y$ as a limit again, you're never going to get rid of $y$ in your final answer. I think we should integrate w.r.t. $x$ first. Check the notation. It differs from book to book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral in the question makes no sense because the ordering of $\mathrm dy$ and $\mathrm dx$ is wrong. Instead it probably ought to read $$
I=\int _0^{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_x^{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin (y^2
)\; \mathrm dy\mathrm dx,$$ that is, $$I=\int _0^{\sqrt{\pi}} G(x)\;\mathrm dx,\qquad G(x)=\int_x^{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin (y^2
)\; \mathrm dy.$$
Then, exchanging the order of integration yields $$I
=\int _0^{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin (y^2
) \left(\int_0^y \mathrm dx\right)\mathrm dy=\int _0^{\sqrt{\pi}}y\sin (y^2
)\; \mathrm dy=\left.-\tfrac12\cos(y^2)\right|_0^{\sqrt{\pi}}=1.$$